# How to insert multiple set of checkboxes with different names in different table column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, checkbox

I have 3 set of checkboxes in my form and I designed it in such a way that if one is checked, the 3 checkboxes for a particular product will be checked. Which means on submission, the 3 set of checkboxes (`itemQuantities[],itemIds[]` and `sectionIds[]`), when I convert them to array using

```
$item_quantities              = $_POST['itemQuantities'];
$item_ids                     = $_POST['itemIds'];
$section_ids                  = $_POST['sectionIds'];
```

They 3 arrays must contain the same number of elements. How can I insert the values of these arrays in one table with one element of the first array into one column, the first element of the second array into the next column, the first element of the third array into the third column and like that.... The number of rows will be the number of elements in one array (Since all arrays have equal elements). For instance:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array(4,5,6);
$array3 = array(7,8,9);
```

In the database, I want to have:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
----------------------
|   1  |   4  |   7  |
|   2  |   5  |   8  |
|   3  |   6  |   9  |
```

How can I achieve this. I have tried using nested foreach loop but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over one of them and use the index of the first on the last two arrays.

```
foreach($_POST['itemQuantities'] as $key => $value) { 
      echo $value . PHP_EOL . $_POST['itemIds'][$key] . PHP_EOL . $_POST['sectionIds'][$key];
}
```

`col1`, `col2`, `col3` is usually a bad db design, I would reconsider that if that is not pseudo names.

Comment: I just used `col1`, `col2`, `col3` as example to ask my question.

Comment: Okay, than this should work. You also should `prepare` outside the `foreach` and only execute the parameterized query in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

if all variables have the same length you can just loop only one array and use the key to another array

```
<?php 
    $array1 = array(1,2,3);
    $array2 = array(4,5,6);
    $array3 = array(7,8,9);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) { 
        echo "value in Row ".($i+1)." is : ".$array1[$i].",".$array2[$i].",".$array3[$i]." ";

    }
?>
```